# MongoDB Query to get deeply nested field from a collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongo-collection

I have a table that looks as given below:

```
[
    {
        _id: "689000",
        category_id: "CC100",
        versions: [
            {
                version_id: 001,
                sub_versions: [
                    {
                        sub_version_code: PS, 
                        verification_name: test
                    },{
                        sub_version_code: PPS, 
                        verification_name: test
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                version_id: 002,
                sub_versions: [
                    {
                        sub_version_code: BS, 
                        verification_name: test
                    },{
                        sub_version_code: BBS, 
                        verification_name: test
                    },
                ]
            },
        ]
    },{
        _id: "689001",
        category_id: "CC100",
        versions: [
            {
                version_id: 001,
                sub_versions: [
                    {
                        sub_version_code: PS, 
                        verification_name: test
                    },{
                        sub_version_code: PPS, 
                        verification_name: test
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                version_id: 002,
                sub_versions: [
                    {
                        sub_version_code: BS, 
                        verification_name: test
                    },{
                        sub_version_code: BBS, 
                        verification_name: test
                    },
                ]
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

The above is a sample of the table structure. Multiple records in the collection can have the same `category_id`. The motive is to query the collection with the `category_id` and return only the `sub_versions_code` .

The expected o/p:

```
[
    {
        _id: "689000",
        codes: [
            sub_version_code: PS,
            sub_version_code: PPS,      
            sub_version_code: BS, 
            sub_version_code: BBS, 
        ]
    },{
        _id: "689001",
        codes: [
            sub_version_code: PS, 
            sub_version_code: PPS, 
            sub_version_code: BS, 
            sub_version_code: BBS, 
        ]
    },
]
```

Since Im just learning MongoDB, Im getting quite confused about aggregate function and how to integrate it into getting a deeply nested field from a collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an aggregation pipeline like this, loop over `versions` array using `$reduce`, and map the `subversions` to an array of codes and concatenate it with the reduced value:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 1,
      codes: {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$versions",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$concatArrays": [
              "$$value",
              {
                "$map": {
                  "input": "$$this.sub_versions",
                  "as": "item",
                  "in": "$$item.sub_version_code"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/S2vAX75Vb21)

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I need to read $reduce, and the the usage of double $$ to understand further. I shall do the same and get back when I have questions. 

Meanwhile, I want to get the output for a particular category_id. I tried writing a $match in the aggregation : 

```db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "category_id": "CC_100"
    },
  },
  {
    "$project": {
   //rest of the query
}
])``` 

This doesnt seem to  generate any output. Cant figure out why. Could you please help me understand.

Comment: The category_id in the question is `CC100`, the playground also has the same value. @bazinga.

Comment: [Updated Playground Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5ghG0jws0i7)

If you see this input data, you can see that the records have 'CC100' and 'CC101' as the ```category_id``` values. I want the ```sub_version_code``` of ```category_id``` = `CC101' alone. That is what I wanted to do with the ```$match``` in the previous comment and which I was failing to achieve

Comment: It seems to be working https://mongoplayground.net/p/oUsdxtaRZEM. @bazinga